# How to save cookie in browser using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, browser, cookies

i've a php page with a form in which i have a checkbox that user can check to select to remember field in browser next login. i'm using that code:

```
if(rememberCheck.checked==true){
       var exdate=new Date();
       exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
       var cod_value=escape(codice.value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
       document.cookie="cod=" + cod_value+";log="+login.value;
}
function getCookie(c_name){
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name){
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
function checkCookie(){
    var cod=getCookie("cod");
    var username = getCookie("login");
    if (username!=null && username!="" && cod!=null && cod!=""){
        var usn = document.getElementsByName('usn')[0];
        var codice = document.getElementsByName('codice')[0];
        usn.value=username;
        codice.value=cod;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i read cookie, it read PHPSESSID=XXXXXX, and not what i write. What can i do? can you help me?

Comment: Maybe is best to use `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie` HTTP headers and in PHP `$_COOKIE` associative array instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['rem_me'])){
   if($_POST['rem_me']=='on'){
      setcookie ("remember", $value, time()+360000);
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with php too.
on login if user checked "remember me", then on php
you can do like

> <?php
>  if( isset($_POST['rem_me']) &&
>   $_POST['rem_me']=='on' )
>  {
>       setcookie ("code", $value, time()+(3600*24*30*12)); //set your cookie
>  }
>  ?>

*if is there any reason why you want to do it with javascript only?*

Comment: i say javascript cause i do setcookie ("code", $value); but when i close browser cookie are deleted and i thought that in javascript cookie could be saved in broswer

Comment: the above comment is the best example of the research based on experience and deduction but with not a trace of reading manuals :)

Comment: understood! i didn't set Expiry date so when i close browser, it trash cookie ;)

Answer (score -1):

why not use jquery $post to set PHP cookies on the server instead, they are easier to work with than js cookies

Comment: i want to save in browser, so when user close browser and go another time to my page cookie must be stored. php is server side, is the same?

Comment: this is a bad solution! sending a request to set a cookie would require reloading the page on success. You'r creating MASSIVE traffic for nothing.
@user1190704 -> look at [this cookie solution with great explanation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Comment: true it does increase server load, but you get better flexibility of php cookies which are easier to work with

Comment: cookie value can be passed back from response so no reloading required

Comment: UNDERSTOOD EVERYTHING! THANKS! ;)